# how to segregate result to different folder by a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to segregate the result, PASSED/FAILED to different folder (PASSED/FAILED folder).

Example:

```
REM 1 = line number
REM 2 = path
pushd %2
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /d /od /b "%~1*.log"') do set "recent=%%x"
echo %recent%
find "PASSED" "%recent%"
set rtn=%errorlevel%
IF rtn=0 (
move %2result_%1.log %2PASSED
) ELSE (
move %2result_%1.log %2FAILED
)
popd
exit /b %rtn%
```

This flow is not working yet.

I need your advice.

Thanks

Comment: That `IF rtn=0 (` looks like a syntax error to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the line `IF rtn=0 (` to `IF %rtn%==0 (`, that's all

Comment: LOL - I hate that bug. I frequently make that mistake when I write an IF statement after a SET /A. I can't tell you how many times I've been momentarily puzzled why my logic doesn't work, then I look at my IF and groan...